# What do I want for lunch?

Tags: word, lateral-thinking, visual, language

I’ve crafted a new puzzle for the community; good luck to you all!

[image: lunch]

Comment: As you have used the [language] tag, does that mean this requires knowledge of other languages to solve?

Comment: @JamesDouglas maybe!

Comment: Would the enigmatic-puzzle tag be appropriate here?

Comment: @Brandon_J nope, I’m pretty spot on with my posts, just a simple language puzzle :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks to me like

> the katakana characters ラーメン for *ramen* overlaid on one another. So perhaps it's ramen noodles for lunch? (But perhaps there's some extra pun that turns the fact of overlaying into a specific kind of ramen? I don't know.)

Comment: Witty ideas. I'm not convinced by either of them, though...

Comment: Only the first one was a serious attempt.